# Keras equivalent of a tensorflow optimizer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I need to translate a NN from TF into Keras.
Kind of straightforward, except for the "momentum" optimizer in Tensorflow.

My best guess is that "momentum" in TF would be SGD in Keras. 
Is this correct?

if so, what are the default hyparparameters "lr, momentum, decay, nesterov" I should set in Keras to match the default call "optimizer=momentum" in TF?

Thank you!

Line to translate:

```
network = regression(
network,
optimizer='momentum',
loss='categorical_crossentropy'
)
```

Comment: Could you add a bit of details? For example, the line of code you're trying to translate and its related code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the TensorFlow code that you're trying to translate is using the high level API TF learn.

By default, the Momentum object from TF learn is initialized with these values :

```
def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.9, lr_decay=0.,
             decay_step=100, staircase=False, use_locking=False,
             name="Momentum"):
```

It also doesn't use the Nesterov momentum. See the [github repo](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/tflearn/optimizers.py#L246) for more information.

To translate it in Keras, I would use :

```
#define all your layers in the network variable
momentum = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, decay=0., nesterov=False)
network.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=momentum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Keras [docs](https://keras.io/optimizers/) on optimizers.

You have two options: either you define an optimizer by name when compiling the model, in which case the default options will apply:

```
model.compile(loss=..., optimizer='sgd')
```

Or you instantiate an Optimizer object separately and specify additional options before passing it to `model.compile()`:

```
from keras import optimizers
optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=..., momentum=...) # specify options such as momentum here
model.compile(loss=..., optimizer=optimizer)
```